# How to check Oracle patches are installed?

Tags: oracle, patch

How do I check that all services and patches are installed in Oracle?

I have an `Oracle 10.2.0.2.0` db version and want to install patches. Also I want to get a list with all services and patches.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Here is an article on how to check and or install new patches :](http://www.aodba.com/en/blog/2014/12/15/manually-patch-oracle-database/)

**To find the OPatch tool setup your database enviroment variables and then issue this comand:**

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/OPatch 
> pwd
/oracle/app/product/10.2.0/db_1/OPatch
```

**To list all the patches applies to your database use the `lsinventory` option:**

```
[oracle@DCG023 8828328]$ opatch lsinventory
Oracle Interim Patch Installer version 11.2.0.3.4
Copyright (c) 2012, Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.

Oracle Home : /u00/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
Central Inventory : /u00/oraInventory
from : /u00/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/oraInst.loc
OPatch version : 11.2.0.3.4
OUI version : 11.2.0.1.0
Log file location : /u00/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/cfgtoollogs/opatch/opatch2013-11-13_13-55-22PM_1.log
Lsinventory Output file location : /u00/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/cfgtoollogs/opatch/lsinv/lsinventory2013-11-13_13-55-22PM.txt


Installed Top-level Products (1):
Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.1.0
There are 1 products installed in this Oracle Home.

Interim patches (1) :
Patch 8405205 : applied on Mon Aug 19 15:18:04 BRT 2013
Unique Patch ID: 11805160
Created on 23 Sep 2009, 02:41:32 hrs PST8PDT
Bugs fixed:
8405205

OPatch succeeded.
```

---

**To list the patches using sql :**

```
select * from registry$history;
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I do it's remotely? Or only i have to use RDP or SSH ? Maybe in Oracle I can this opatch remotely or something else?

Comment: You will need RDP or SSH access to those hosts/nodes.

Comment: and I can't use SQL for getting the same result. Only opatch?

Comment: select * from registry$history;

Comment: is this was what you were looking for mark it as answered and Up_One !!

Comment: Another one question:
In your example on server installed 1 patch "8405205"
I don't see for which component this patch used. @Up_One

Comment: this patch fixed a bug , in my OEM repo !

Comment: The SQL solution shows only patch sets and patch set updates, not individual patches.
To see what an individual patch fixes, you should look it up on the Oracle support web site.

Answer (score 9):

I understand the original post is for Oracle 10 but this is for reference by anyone else who finds it via Google.

Under Oracle 12c, I found that that my registry$history is empty. 
This works instead:

```
select * from registry$sqlpatch;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.

Comment: You can use dba_registry_sqlpatch too.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you need "sys." before:

```
select * from sys.registry$history;
```